# How to mock a final static variable that is being set by a static method?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I have looked at other questions which are similar to this, but they don't have this exact use case.

If I have code like the following:

```
private static final String SOME_CONSANT = SomeStaticClass.getString();
```

How would I go about mocking this so that it doesn't always return a null pointer exception?  I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(SomeStaticClass.class);
when(SomeStaticClass.getString(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("test");
```

I'm at a loss. Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: It would be much better to refactor your code so you don't need to hack it to this degree just to test it.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change too much as the static method is legacy and I need to use it

Comment: In that case, do you need to test it? If you are using it from your code, I would try mocking at that level instead.

Comment: *does not seem to work either* is not a helpful description of your problem. As bad as it is, mocking static stuff is straight forward with PowerMock; just follow their [documentation](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/mockstatic). If that doesn't help, put up a **full** [mcve] !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I presume that the main problem of yours is that you are trying to mock different method.

With this code `when(SomeStaticClass.getString(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn("test");` you mock method `SomeStaticClass.getString(String parameter)`, however, in your original code you have `SomeStaticClass.getString()`.